# How can I roll a Ball in unity in the direction my cam is looking?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, move

I have a Sphere which is able to rotate in all directions. 
With `WASD`it is possible to move it forward/backwards and to the side.

But now I want that it moves in the direction I am looking. 
I started to code that it can rotate side wards due moving the mouse on the X-Axis. This works fine but when use the Forward key it obviously still moved in the worlds "W" direction so Z-Positive. 
I tried to use

```
rigid.AddRelativeForce(transform.forward*inputY, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

which should move the Ball in its "forward" direction and this works ok But cause its a ball and its rotates along its own axis the forward direction is changing all the time while the ball is rolling.

**So here is my question:** How can I give a Sphere with rotations a Force in the direction I am looking with the Cam.

**Edit:** 
It is obviously possible to take the forward vector of the camera but then I still had the problem that the camera started rotation around the ball.

I first tried to add an extra object which only rotates on y and the camera follows this object but that was not that clean. So I came up with the dummy rotation which you can see in the pined answer below.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please post them as multiple, separate questions.

Comment: How about using the direction you are looking with the Camera then?

Comment: @derHugo the problem with this was, that i wanted my cam to smoothly folllow. It would not always be there where u wanna go. But I foxed it as you can see downwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for it. Its a little workaround. I get a virtual rotation from my mousX moveing and add it to the ball and the Camera. To the Ball i add it with the Space.world and to the camera with quaternions.

I try to give you a short example:

```
//DummyRotation which I add to the object I wanna move
public class DummyRotation : MonoBehaviour {
    public Quaternion rotX = Quaternion.identity;
    public float rotSpeedX;
    void Update() {
        float mouseX = Mathf.Clamp(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*rotSpeedX, -15, 15);
        rotX *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(mouseX, Vector3.up);
    }
}
```

```
//Movement Script
public partial class SphereMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody rigid;
    public float speed = 3.0f;

    void Start() {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    void Update() {
        dummyRotation = GetComponent<DummyRotation>().rotX;
        checkKeys(); //just checks which keys are pressed
        if (forward) {
            rigid.AddForce(dummyRotation * new Vector3(0, 0, speed));
        } else if (backward) {
            rigid.AddForce(dummyRotation * new Vector3(0, 0, -speed * 0.9f));
        }
    }
}
```

```
//The Camera Script
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CameraFollowTarget : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform camTarget;
    public View view; //this is a custom class which contains pitch chaw roll and offset
    private void Update() {
        View view = views.ElementAt(currentView);

        Vector3 pitchYawRoll = view.rotation;
        Vector3 offsetPosition = view.offsetPosition;
        Quaternion dummyRot = camTarget.GetComponent<DummyRotation>().rotX;
        Vector3 newPos = camTarget.position + dummyRot * offsetPosition;

        transform.position = Lerp(transform.position, newPos, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give me a moment i will try to give an example

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko example is here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the camera direction.

```
Camera.main.transform.forward
```

instead of the `transform.forward` of the ball.

Comment: Note: In a frequent call like `FixedUpdate` the usage of `Camera.main` is quite inefficient and you would rather want to store it once in a field (either by code using `Camera.main` e.g. in `Start` or via drag and drop in the Inspector if possible) and then reuse the reference for the repeated calls.

Comment: That would be possible but the problem is that my cam should also have a smooth factor. So the Object could already be rotated 90° when the Cam is only at 80° an so it would move in the wrong direction.